# AWS Cloud9: Cannot open environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud9

I have created an environment in AWS Cloud9 with a Python Lambda function.
This was working fine and for several days I was adding functionality.
However one day the environment failed to open. After several minutes of loading it displayed an error message:

> This is taking longer than expected.
>   If you think there might be an issue, contact AWS Support.
>   It might be caused by VPC configuration issues.
>   Please check documentation: 
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/vpc-settings.html?icmpid=docs_ac9_console

I looked at the suggested link, but I don't think the VPC is the issue. I didn't make any changes to it. Moreover I am able to make new environments and open them.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Can you go to the EC2 console and take a look whats going on with cloud9 instance (after you try to login to cloud9)? It should have a name starting with 'aws-cloud9-gameday-development'. If it is in the Running state, etc?

Comment: Thanks Lech. It was in the running state.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out the problem was the default t2.micro (1 GiB RAM) instance that is used to run Cloud9. I was probably running out of memory. Moving my environment to t2.small (2 GiB RAM) solved the problem.

Documentation on moving environments:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/move-environment.html

Comment: I just want to add, micro didn't work, neither did small. I had to select a LARGE, just to create a cloud9 instance, that was only used once to create a lambda layer build with the right linux libs. smh. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

I had the error message:

"This is taking longer than expected. The delay may be caused by high CPU usage in your environment, or your T2 or T3 instance is running out of burstable CPU capacity credits, or there are VPC configuration issues."

What I did to solve it was to have my internet gateway attached to a VPC and for that VPC to have a public subnet.

I found this link to be useful to help solve this issue particularly when it states the
VPC requirements for AWS Cloud9: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/vpc-settings.html?icmpid=docs_ac9_console

Comment: To me, his specific route settings made it work: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/vpc-settings.html?icmpid=docs_ac9_console#vpc-settings-requirements-route-table-settings

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer above but just to expand with details on what I did:

1. I created a VPC attached to an Internet Gateway
2. create a route table and associate with subnet
3. Route table with routing to the subnet (making it public) and another routing to the internet gateway

This solved my problem.

Comment: I tried doing this, but how do you attach the newly created vpc with the cloud9 ec2 instance? I did all vpc settings as mentioned, created subnet, created internet gateway, even created network interface and security group. But unable to attach it to cloud9 instance.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was different:
I changed the Region to Ohio from N. Virginia and that fixed the problem. But, it could be timing issue where N. Virginia was having problem.

Answer (score 0):

There might have some processes hanging that will blew up memory.
Reboot the instance and try reloading the environment.