# AWS Cloud9: Environment Stops Responding

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud9-ide, vpc, cloud9, aws-cloud9

I trying to setup AWS Cloud9 and am running into a wall each time I try to setup my environments.  Once I create the environment and start following this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/sample-lamp.html to configure the LAMP server, through the Cloud9 IDE terminal, the environment will just stop responding. Once I try to reload the IDE I get the follow error;

> [Cannot connect to instance error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsl4Q.png)

Rebooting the instance doesn't seem to resolve the error message.  But any time I make a fresh instance it will let me work from anywhere to 30 seconds to 90 seconds before it stops responding.

I have looked through my VPC port settings, as well as security group settings, and they both appear to the correct.

> [VPC inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qsvt.png) [VPC outbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JFPg.png) [Security Group inbound
>   rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz7nS.png) [Security Group outbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9upPx.png)

Additionally, I was using the default **t2.micro** instance until I read this post [AWS Cloud9: Cannot open environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103410/aws-cloud9-cannot-open-environment) and have tried with the **t2.small** but I am still getting the same results.

Any help with where else to look or what else to try would be much appreciated!

Edit: It appears to be random when it stops and freezes, for example when making a m4.large instance. It froze while I was setting up the **sudo mysql_secure_installation**.

[Once I typed "Y" it wouldn't let me press enter. Reloading the IDE gave me the VPC error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni1g0.png)

Comment: Yes, I get the same type of "freezing up" in the IDE the last couple months. It is some sort of javascript error going on with the Cloud9 IDE. Something is running out of control. If you let the page site for a while, you'll eventually get the "Page unresponsive: Kill Page or Wait" option from the browser, which shows that it is definitely a Javascript error of some sort.

I hope they fix this issue soon. I posted on the AWS/Cloud9 forum about it.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO! When I use cloud9 I tend to use m4.large for anything that's non-trivial. If you're running Apache and MySQL on the same host I would definitely try the m4.large instance. It's $0.10/hr ([pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/)) so you could try it out fairly cheaply. I'm guessing that's the root of the issue. If you're still having the issue please repost here and we can check further.

Just to confirm:
- You can connect to the instance at least once (even if for a few seconds)
- You see the IDE and can type for 30-60 seconds before it stops responding

If you can't connect that's likely a different issue.

Comment: Yes, I am able to create the instance through the Cloud9 dashboard and log into it and start using the terminal window to configure the LAMP settings.  I will try using a m4.large and get back to you!

Comment: Tried using m4.large.  Getting the same behavior, while running through the guide (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/sample-lamp.html)

I entered [ sudo service apache2 start && sudo service apache2 status ] into the terminal and it froze.

Comment: The terminal froze or the IDE froze? Also can you confirm which OS you are using - Ubuntu or Amazon Linux?

Comment: Both froze. The terminal would no longer let me type and when I tried to open the Readme file, that was created with the instance, it just sits and spins.

Comment: I'm trying to re-create - Amazon Linux or Ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry, Ubuntu is the OS I am using.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What region are you trying? Also, a few other questions - are you starting with a new environment and then running the exact commands found on the page you referenced?

Comment: I am in us-east-1 (N. Virginia). I am  going to the Cloud9 console and creating a new EC2 environment from that interface. Once the environment loads into the IDE, I am opening the terminal window and then going through the commands on the page, correct.

Comment: Can you confirm that your VPC has a public subnet (i.e. has an internet gateway)?

Comment: Also, are you changing any of the default settings when launching the instance?

Comment: @mistertee It looks like it's an issue with the IDE. It randomly locks up. (sometimes it will go for a few hours with no problem, sometimes just for a minute or two before locking up). The browser eventually says "Page Unresponsive: Wait or Kill". This leads me to believe its some sort of Javascript error with their IDE.

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to connect to Cloud9 from a tablet? Or from a PC? It does indeed sound like a client side error so maybe next time it happens you could respond "Wait" and try to grab a trace from the console and share it here. Also, if you don't mind could you post the specs for whatever device you're using to access Cloud9?